# Xperia z1 loss of camera functionality unlocking bootloader

Tags: camera, bootloader, sony

Sony xperia z1

Are Sony working on a fix for the broken camera problem when unlocking the bootloader of Xperia z1?

any estimate of arravial of such an fix?

Comment: you should post in xperia forums

Comment: is this a development related question? please provide more information.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about using an electronic device, not about programming.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here.
For now, you can just root on .534 then upgrade to .257
Use vRoot on .534 then with SuperSU Pro use OTA survival mode and upgrade to .257 with OTA.

If you unlock the bootloader, your DRM keys will be lost, so the camera will stop working correctly (no auto focus, etc.)

Unfortunatly, there is no way to flash a custom kernel without losing the camera functionality.
Tried also to contact sony, but the support for developers is a bit dead.